# CSS transform animation very laggy and slow on Android Cordova app

Tags: android, css, cordova, css-animations

I'm delevoping a cordova app for Android.
I have this HTML `<ul>`:

```
<ul>
        <li class="animation" > 
                    ....
        </li>
</ul>
```

and this is the CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes list{
    from{
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to{
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.animation{
    -webkit-animation-name: list;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
     -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;

    animation-name: list;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

the result is that every element of the list will be shown from left to right with a little fading.

Now the problem is that this animation is really laggy and slow on my HTC ONE with android 4.4.3. 
On the other hand I notice that the animation is perfect and smooth when I run my app on Chrome (on my desktop computer) using Ripple Emulator.

Do you have any idea why I have this problem and how to fix it?
I also tried to use only `translate` and to add translateZ(0), but same problem.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, Im wondering did you find any solution to this? Is it simply a performance issue to do with using a hybrid solution instead of native app? I have the exact same problem now. The animation isnt great at all